# Round raster values to decimal place in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro

I have a floating raster with values to the sixth decimal place, but I need these values to be rounded to the tenth. In ArcGIS Pro, the Raster Calculator only has RoundUp or RoundDown functions, which still round to the nearest whole number. Also, I need to keep the Raster as a floating type, so I can do the Int process of multiplying the float, change to int, then divide, etc. Is it possible to round these raster values while maintaining the raster type as a float?

Comment: So you have a number such 123.124467 and you want to do what to it? I'm no mathematician but rounding that to 10th decimal place simply returns that number as there are no numbers beyond the 6th decimal place. What you ask makes no sense to me. If you want to see 123.1244670000 I don't think computers store numbers in that manner.

Comment: if I have 123.124467, I want 123.1... to the 1/10th decimal place,

Comment: You can multiply by 10, round to nearest whole value, then divide by 10. (Round nearest might be add 0.5, then round down.)

Comment: `Int(your_raster * 10 + 0.5) / 10.0` will output a float type